# How to run a .py module?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, rdf, factorization

I've got zero experience with Python. I have looked around some tutorial materials, but it seems difficult to understand a advanced code. So I came here for a more specific answer. 
For me the mission is to redo the code in my computer.

Here is the scenario:

I'm a graduate student studying tensor factorization in relation learning. A paper[1] providing a code to run this algorithm, as follows:

```
import logging, time
from numpy import dot, zeros, kron, array, eye, argmax
from numpy.linalg import qr, pinv, norm, inv 
from scipy.linalg import eigh
from numpy.random import rand

__version__ = "0.1" 
__all__ = ['rescal', 'rescal_with_random_restarts']

__DEF_MAXITER = 500
__DEF_INIT = 'nvecs'
__DEF_PROJ = True
__DEF_CONV = 1e-5
__DEF_LMBDA = 0

_log = logging.getLogger('RESCAL') 

def rescal_with_random_restarts(X, rank, restarts=10, **kwargs):
    """
    Restarts RESCAL multiple time from random starting point and 
    returns factorization with best fit.
    """
    models = []
    fits = []
    for i in range(restarts):
        res = rescal(X, rank, init='random', **kwargs)
        models.append(res)
        fits.append(res[2])
    return models[argmax(fits)]

def rescal(X, rank, **kwargs):
    """
    RESCAL 

    Factors a three-way tensor X such that each frontal slice 
    X_k = A * R_k * A.T. The frontal slices of a tensor are 
    N x N matrices that correspond to the adjecency matrices 
    of the relational graph for a particular relation.

    For a full description of the algorithm see: 
      Maximilian Nickel, Volker Tresp, Hans-Peter-Kriegel, 
      "A Three-Way Model for Collective Learning on Multi-Relational Data",
      ICML 2011, Bellevue, WA, USA

    Parameters
    ----------
    X : list
        List of frontal slices X_k of the tensor X. The shape of each X_k is ('N', 'N')
    rank : int 
        Rank of the factorization
    lmbda : float, optional 
        Regularization parameter for A and R_k factor matrices. 0 by default 
    init : string, optional
        Initialization method of the factor matrices. 'nvecs' (default) 
        initializes A based on the eigenvectors of X. 'random' initializes 
        the factor matrices randomly.
    proj : boolean, optional 
        Whether or not to use the QR decomposition when computing R_k.
        True by default 
    maxIter : int, optional 
        Maximium number of iterations of the ALS algorithm. 500 by default. 
    conv : float, optional 
        Stop when residual of factorization is less than conv. 1e-5 by default

    Returns 
    -------
    A : ndarray 
        array of shape ('N', 'rank') corresponding to the factor matrix A
    R : list
        list of 'M' arrays of shape ('rank', 'rank') corresponding to the factor matrices R_k 
    f : float 
        function value of the factorization 
    iter : int 
        number of iterations until convergence 
    exectimes : ndarray 
        execution times to compute the updates in each iteration
    """

    # init options
    ainit = kwargs.pop('init', __DEF_INIT)
    proj = kwargs.pop('proj', __DEF_PROJ)
    maxIter = kwargs.pop('maxIter', __DEF_MAXITER)
    conv = kwargs.pop('conv', __DEF_CONV)
    lmbda = kwargs.pop('lmbda', __DEF_LMBDA)
    if not len(kwargs) == 0:
        raise ValueError( 'Unknown keywords (%s)' % (kwargs.keys()) )

    sz = X[0].shape
    dtype = X[0].dtype 
    n = sz[0]
    k = len(X) 

    _log.debug('[Config] rank: %d | maxIter: %d | conv: %7.1e | lmbda: %7.1e' % (rank, 
        maxIter, conv, lmbda))
    _log.debug('[Config] dtype: %s' % dtype)

    # precompute norms of X 
    normX = [norm(M)**2 for M in X]
    Xflat = [M.flatten() for M in X]
    sumNormX = sum(normX)

    # initialize A
    if ainit == 'random':
        A = array(rand(n, rank), dtype=dtype)
    elif ainit == 'nvecs':
        S = zeros((n, n), dtype=dtype)
        T = zeros((n, n), dtype=dtype)
        for i in range(k):
            T = X[i]
            S = S + T + T.T
        evals, A = eigh(S,eigvals=(n-rank,n-1))
    else :
        raise 'Unknown init option ("%s")' % ainit

    # initialize R
    if proj:
        Q, A2 = qr(A)
        X2 = __projectSlices(X, Q)
        R = __updateR(X2, A2, lmbda)
    else :
        R = __updateR(X, A, lmbda)

    # compute factorization
    fit = fitchange = fitold = f = 0
    exectimes = []
    ARAt = zeros((n,n), dtype=dtype)
    for iter in xrange(maxIter):
        tic = time.clock()
        fitold = fit
        A = __updateA(X, A, R, lmbda)
        if proj:
            Q, A2 = qr(A)
            X2 = __projectSlices(X, Q)
            R = __updateR(X2, A2, lmbda)
        else :
            R = __updateR(X, A, lmbda)

        # compute fit value
        f = lmbda*(norm(A)**2)
        for i in range(k):
            ARAt = dot(A, dot(R[i], A.T))
            f += normX[i] + norm(ARAt)**2 - 2*dot(Xflat[i], ARAt.flatten()) + lmbda*(R[i].flatten()**2).sum()
        f *= 0.5

        fit = 1 - f / sumNormX
        fitchange = abs(fitold - fit)

        toc = time.clock()
        exectimes.append( toc - tic )
        _log.debug('[%3d] fit: %.5f | delta: %7.1e | secs: %.5f' % (iter, 
            fit, fitchange, exectimes[-1]))
        if iter > 1 and fitchange < conv:
            break
    return A, R, f, iter+1, array(exectimes)

def __updateA(X, A, R, lmbda):
    n, rank = A.shape
    F = zeros((n, rank), dtype=X[0].dtype)
    E = zeros((rank, rank), dtype=X[0].dtype)

    AtA = dot(A.T,A)
    for i in range(len(X)):
        F += dot(X[i], dot(A, R[i].T)) + dot(X[i].T, dot(A, R[i]))
        E += dot(R[i], dot(AtA, R[i].T)) + dot(R[i].T, dot(AtA, R[i]))
    A = dot(F, inv(lmbda * eye(rank) + E))
    return A

def __updateR(X, A, lmbda):
    r = A.shape[1]
    R = []
    At = A.T    
    if lmbda == 0:
        ainv = dot(pinv(dot(At, A)), At)
        for i in range(len(X)):
            R.append( dot(ainv, dot(X[i], ainv.T)) )
    else :
        AtA = dot(At, A)
        tmp = inv(kron(AtA, AtA) + lmbda * eye(r**2))
        for i in range(len(X)):
            AtXA = dot(At, dot(X[i], A)) 
            R.append( dot(AtXA.flatten(), tmp).reshape(r, r) )
    return R

def __projectSlices(X, Q):
    q = Q.shape[1]
    X2 = []
    for i in range(len(X)):
        X2.append( dot(Q.T, dot(X[i], Q)) )
    return X2
```

It's boring to paste such a long code but there is no other way to figure out my problems. I'm sorry about this.

I import this module and pass them arguments according to the author's [website](http://www.cip.ifi.lmu.de/~nickel/doc/rescal/index.html):

```
import pickle, sys
from rescal import rescal

rank = sys.argv[1]
X = pickle.load('us-presidents.pickle')
A, R, f, iter, exectimes = rescal(X, rank, lmbda=1.0)
```

The dataset us-presidents.rdf can be found [here](http://www.cip.ifi.lmu.de/~nickel/).

My questions are:

1. According to the code note, the tensor X is a list. I don't quite understand this, how do I relate a list to a tensor in Python? Can I understand tensor = list in Python?
2. Should I convert RDF format to a triple(subject, predicate, object) format first? I'm not sure of the data structure of X. How do I assignment values to X by hand?
3. Then, how to run it?

I paste the author's code without his authorization, is it an act of infringement? if so, I am so sorry and I will delete it soon.

The problems may be a little bored, but these are important to me. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[1] Maximilian Nickel, Volker Tresp, Hans-Peter Kriegel,
A Three-Way Model for Collective Learning on Multi-Relational Data,
in Proceedings of the 28th International Conference on Machine Learning, 2011 , Bellevue, WA, USA

Comment: To run a module simply do: python modulename

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer Q2: you need to transform the RDF and save it before you can load it from the file 'us-presidents.pickle'. The author of that code probably did that once because the Python native pickle format loads faster. As the pickle format includes the datatype of the data, it is possible that `X` is some numpy class instance and you would need either an example pickle file as used by this code, or some code doing the pickle.dump to figure out how to convert from RDF to this particular pickle file as `rescal` expects it.

So this might answer Q1: the tensor consists of a list of elements. From the code you can see  that the `X` parameter to rescal has a length (`k = len(X)` ) and can be indexed (`T = X[i]`). So it elements are used as a list (even if it might be some other datatype, that just behaves as such.

As an aside: If you are not familiar with Python and are just interested in the result of the computation, you might get more help contacting the author of the software.

Comment: cool, now the question is how to get the file 'us-presidents.pickle' by transformation or contracting to the author, I will try it.

Answer (score 1):

> 1. According to the code note, the tensor X is a list. I don't quite understand this, how do I relate a list to a tensor in Python? Can I
>      understand tensor = list in Python?

Not necessarily but the author of the code has decided to represent the tensor data as a list data structure. As the comments indicate, the list X contains:

> List of frontal slices X_k of the tensor X. The shape of each X_k is ('N', 'N')

That means the tensor is repesented as a list of tuples: `[(N, N), ..., (N, N)]`.

> 1. I'm not sure of the data structure of X. How do I assignment values to X by hand?

Now that we now the data structure of X, we can assign values to it using assignment. The following will assign the tuple `(1, 3)` to the first position in the list X (as the first position is at index 0, the second at position 1, et cetera):

```
X[0] = (1, 3)
```

Similarly, the following will assign the tuple `(2, 4)` to the second position:

```
X[1] = (2, 4)
```

Comment: Thanks, but when you assign X[0] = (1,3), a ERROR occurs: File "C:\Python27\rescal.py", line 88, in rescal
    sz = X[0].shape
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'shape'

Comment: In that case the elements of X are not tuple but objects of a different type. Try `print type(X[0])` before doing any assignments to check what the type is and then construct objects of that type. You can then assign those objects to X (e.g., `X[0] = ...`).

Comment: I found the shape method in numpy [tutorial](http://www.scipy.org/Tentative_NumPy_Tutorial#head-62ef2d3c0a5b4b7d6fdc48e4a60fe48b1ffe5006), Thanks a lot!